# Webpack change output.filename per entry chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack

With Webpack I'd like to have one of my entry chunks not have a hash at all and use a different naming convention to another entry file.

Using the following Webpack config:

```
entry: {
   app: path.join(__dirname, '../src/app'),
  'loader/loader': path.join(__dirname, '../src/loader/loader')
}.
output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

**The undesired output:**

[image]

**The desired output:**

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebpackManifestPlugin. It will create file manifest.json, you can parse it and get real name of your entry file

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin